# Listing MySQL Array in HTML Table

Tags: php, html, mysql

Ihave one script to list data from MySQL in HTML Table. Inserting in MySQL is dynamical and each category have diffrent number of fields. Because data is dynamicaly inserted in MySQL table Content I have record for each FiledContent. Now when I'm selecting data I have non splited array data and in HTML table I'm getting one content field for all records. I want to spit records from Content and get splited Content for each Field Name in HTML Head Table.

With this script:

```
$sql = "SELECT FieldContent FROM Content JOIN Fields ON Content.ForField = Fields.FieldName WHERE Fields.ForUser = 'Viruss' AND Fields.ForCategory = 'Otpornici'";
    if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<th>".$row["FieldContent"]."</th>";       
    }
```

I'm getting this as result:

[image]

Comment: Anyone? I'm expected more.

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand quite what you are asking. What is the expected result? Can you put up a jsfiddle highlighting the problem

Comment: If we use picture as an example each "Test Content" must be displayed under "Test Field" like first 3 results.

Comment: FYI @Miljan another reason why people might not be replying is that you don't have a good answer acceptance ratio. Most people like when you accept the answer that they've written and just going back on your profile seems like its not that common

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using the `<th>` tag wrong.

`<th>` stands for table header, so the table will continue producing headers instead of rows. You need to use the `<tr>` tag to make a table row.

```
$sql = "SELECT FieldContent FROM Content JOIN Fields ON Content.ForField = ...";
if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$row["FieldContent"]['testcontent1']</td>";
        echo "<td>$row["FieldContent"]['testcontent2']</td>";
        echo "<td>$row["FieldContent"]['testcontent3']</td>";
        echo "</tr>";    
    }   
}
```

You should also use the `<td>` tag to represent table data.

---

Now you have to split your content into multiple rows. It is NOT recommended you store data like this. You can do comma separated values or another method

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr>";
     $split = explode(' ', $row["FieldContent"]); // Split up the whole string
     $chunks = array_chunk($split, 3); // Make groups of 3 words
     $result = array_map(function($chunk) { return implode(' ', $chunk); }, $chunks);
     foreach($result as $value)
          echo "<td>$value</td>";
      echo "</tr>";    
}
```

Comment: This is not working because I have listed all records in one $row["FieldContent"], and not always listed 3 Fields. In need something like foreach in while to list all $row["FieldContent"] in <td>...</td> and than close with </tr>

Comment: Can you add what the content of a `print_r` on fieldcontent is?

Comment: I don't clearly understand you where to add content. Witch print_r?

Comment: Run the method `var_dump` or `print_r` on the variable `$row[FieldContent]` and paste the output in your question please

Comment: I have ran print_r and thisis an result                                                   Test Content 1
Test Content 2
Test Content 3                                                                                   Test Content 1
Test Content 2
Test Content 3
Test Content 1
Test Content 2
Test Content 3

Comment: Can you recomend me a better method to store and list data. Witch PHP functions I need to use?

Comment: Well at LEAST I would recommend using the function `implode` when you put all your content in the database and use the function `explode` when you take it out. Better than that would be to use a database that supports array types.

Comment: I found on google that I can serialize data when inserting in MySQL. What do you think about it?